# skipping error Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist - in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm running a loop that reads many txt files in my computer and I'm willing to merge them all into a big data frame.

```
listofdf <- list()

for (i in 1:5) {
    temp_data <- read_delim(files_to_read[i], delim = "\t")

temp_data <- temp_data %>%
    select(!c("Analysis.Index", "Participant.Name", "Identity", "Landmarks"))

  listofdf[[i]] <- temp_data
}
```

My problem is that some of these data frames had a columns and other dont - which means that I cant use the function

```
 do.call(rbind,listofdf)
```

to merge them all.

when I try to use "select" inside the loop I get the error:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.

x Column `Analysis.Index` doesn't exist.
```

which make sense because not all data frames has those extra unneeded columns but the problem is that this error breaks my loop and stops it.

what can I do? Thank you!

Comment: try `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(files_to_read, data.table::fread), use.names=TRUE, fill = TRUE)` to get one large data.table of all files, and subset afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any_of`, it selects/drops only those columns which exist in the data and ignores the ones which are not present. For example, with `mtcars` dataset :

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% select(any_of(c('mpg', 'mpg1')))

#                     mpg
#Mazda RX4           21.0
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
#Datsun 710          22.8
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
#...
#...
```

Use `map_df` to combine `files_to_read` in one dataframe.

```
cols <- c("Analysis.Index", "Participant.Name", "Identity", "Landmarks")
combine_data <- map_df(files_to_read, 
                  ~read_delim(.x, delim = "\t") %>% select(!any_of(cols)))
```